# Updating iOS SDK: Does it force all users to update?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

I have what may be a simple question (and perhaps silly)... If you release an iOS app, let's say its running version 4.x, but then you push out an update to the AppStore, that compiles using a newer SDK, and specify in requirements you need that SDK version, what happens to the users who don't update their os?

Am I to assume they don't get the notification to update via app store as their handset OS is not compatible? 
Cheers

Comment: I believe, (from having this happen to me as a user), it still alerts it has an update available, but won't allow the user to download it without updating the OS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The existing users already have an older version of the app which works, and they won't even see an update for the app.

Comment: I guess Apple fixed this. Good. I hated getting updates that I could not update to.

Comment: Unless they look in desktop iTunes.

Comment: I'm so used to updating from iTunes on the desktop that I would not have pegged the issue from performing an update from there with older hardware.

Comment: Good point, I don't know what happens if you update from iTunes and try to sync. But starting with iOS 5, Apple is trying to make everything cloudy, so connecting to iTunes will no longer be a requirement to be able to use your iPhone or iPad or iWhatever.

Comment: Any idea what would happen if the user (still on iOS 4) deletes your app.  Would they then be able to go and re-install like normal (by looking under purchases in the app store).  I would imagine that the app store doesn't continue to serve the older (iOS 4) version of your app.  Does this mean that the user cannot reinstall the app until updating?

Answer (score 0):

When you create the application, you state in the properties for the application what the minimum iOS revision is that is supported for that application. You can compile an app using a newer version of the SDK targetting the older OS.

You should guard against performing calls that are only available on the newer release using the recommended mechanism from the documentation (Look up the SDK compatibility guide in the docs).

Marking an application for a newer release of the OS without adding features that are needed by the newer OS is adding unnecessary restrictions to the app that would otherwise allow it to run on older releases (not everyone has the latest iPhone, iPad or iPod Touch)

I've developed applications on Windows 7 that run on Windows 2000. It is doable, you just spend a lot of time working around missing features.